# How to ignore compiler flags in pip?

Tags: python, gcc, pip, reinforcement-learning

I'm trying to install mujoco-py, when I try `pip install mujoco_py` in my maxOS 10.12 with python 3.5 in anaconda, I got

```
  /usr/local/bin/gcc-7 -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -I/Users/Shangtong/anaconda2/envs/Python3.5/include -I/Users/Shangtong/anaconda2/envs/Python3.5/include -Wno-error=unused-command-line-argument-hard-error-in-future -Wno-error=unused-command-line-argument-hard-error-in-future -Wno-error=unused-command-line-argument-hard-error-in-future -DONMAC -Imujoco_py -I/private/var/folders/6j/gtq1cx25611ck3bft9rnfxkh0000gn/T/pip-build-3r460esi/mujoco-py/mujoco_py -I/Users/Shangtong/.mujoco/mjpro150/include -I/Users/Shangtong/anaconda2/envs/Python3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/numpy/core/include -I/Users/Shangtong/anaconda2/envs/Python3.5/include/python3.5m -c /private/var/folders/6j/gtq1cx25611ck3bft9rnfxkh0000gn/T/pip-build-3r460esi/mujoco-py/mujoco_py/cymj.c -o /private/var/folders/6j/gtq1cx25611ck3bft9rnfxkh0000gn/T/pip-build-3r460esi/mujoco-py/mujoco_py/generated/_pyxbld_MacExtensionBuilder/temp.macosx-10.6-x86_64-3.5/private/var/folders/6j/gtq1cx25611ck3bft9rnfxkh0000gn/T/pip-build-3r460esi/mujoco-py/mujoco_py/cymj.o -fopenmp -w
  cc1: error: -Werror=unused-command-line-argument-hard-error-in-future: no option -Wunused-command-line-argument-hard-error-in-future
  cc1: error: -Werror=unused-command-line-argument-hard-error-in-future: no option -Wunused-command-line-argument-hard-error-in-future
  cc1: error: -Werror=unused-command-line-argument-hard-error-in-future: no option -Wunused-command-line-argument-hard-error-in-future
  error: command '/usr/local/bin/gcc-7' failed with exit status 1
```

I have to install `gcc` because it doesn't accept `clang`. It seems `gcc` doesn't ignore this unknown flag. I tried

```
ARCHFLAGS=-Wno-error=unused-command-line-argument-hard-error-in-future pip install mujoco_py
```

But it didn't help. Is there any way that `gcc` can ignore this unknown flag?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally find a solution.
First install clang-omp via `brew install clang-omp`. Then link clang-omp to gcc-7 via `sudo ln -s /usr/local/bin/clang-omp /usr/local/bin/gcc-7`. Then you should be able to run mujoco151. Note you may also need to `brew uninstall glfw` to solve a conflict.